# How to determine if after scrolling the bottom of browser window has reached top of DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to solve this issue with jQuery/Javascript:

When the browser scrolls down and the bottom of the window reaches the top of the footer DIV, action a CSS code change.

Example of problem:
   https://elodywedding.com/blog
(Ensure your browser window is mobile-sized.)

If you scroll down to footer on a smaller resolution, the footer floats statically and sits above the "tags" DIV.  I would need to set position back to absolute.

Any ideas how to detect when the scrolling causes the window to reach the top of the footer DIV?

Comment: You need to make your footer "narrower" on smaller displays and/or change z-index of "tags" div. FYI: someone down voted your question because you haven't shown how you have tried to solve the problem and/or have not included any code... replicate your prob in a JSFiddle and add link...

Comment: I'd break your problematic code out into the smallest unit possible - and submit it on something like JSfiddle.net so people with answers can help more easily.

Comment: Hello, its complicated to adding it to jsfiddle. I would like just help with condition which check if is footer already visible (or reached by bottom of window).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this appears to work: https://jsfiddle.net/zk49cuy7/

```
<style type="text/css">
#body {
    height:1500px;
    background-color:red;
}
#footer {
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>

<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

jQuery(function($){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight >= $('#footer').offset().top)
        {
            console.log('BOTTOM');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('NOT BOTTOM');
        }
    });
});
```

Binding to window scroll and checking whether the scroll top + window height is greater than the offset top of the footer.